# Set default value on select

Tags: javascript

I have an ionic select with a list of users, 
In this list I have an option that will redirect me to another page:
in my list I have an item that will act like a button at the moment it will select it and redirect me, I only want it to act like a button and don't be selected, so the selector keep the first item of the list selected

> My list:

[My Image so you can understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTGGy.png)

Is there a way to handle this please ?

```
  <ion-select interface="popover" [ngModel]="selecteduser._id" (ngModelChange)="selectUser($event)" (ionChange)="onChange($event)">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user._id">
      </ion-content>{{ getUserNickname(user }} </ion-option>
    <ion-option>Go To Modal</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
```

So I want when I click on my Go To Modal, it will redirect me to my modal.
without selecting it.

There is my ts

```
  onChange(value: any) {
    if (value === 'Go To Modal') {
      this.openConfig()
    }
  }

  openConfig() {
    this.modalCtrl.create(configModal).present()
    console.log('heeey')
  }

  selectUser(userId: string) {
    this.selectedUser = this.users.find(b => b._id === userId)
    this.onSelect.emit(this.selectedUser)
  }
```

Comment: Could [a menu](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#menus) be a better fit for what you want? Or at least a list of buttons?

Comment: @Aankhen, i need to do an eventhandler on my two last item that's it but didn't know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

In your html code: extra closing tag found  `</ion-content>` and your Go To Modal option should be contains some value like `<ion-option value="Go To Modal">Go To Modal</ion-option>` as your other option contains some value

Comment: Okey, add it but nothing changed, when i select the Go To modal, instead of only act like a button it's get selected and redirect me, i want it to only act like a button without getting selected.